# system.invalidoperationexception sequence contains no elements at system.linq.enumerable.first[TSource]{IEnumaberable`1 source}

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, sequence, element, visual-studio-2019

I installed an updated visual studio in 2019. After that, I opened my xamarin application and ran the app. It's built successfully. Before opening the application in the emulator I got the below issue.

[image]

Comment: same here, problem ocurred when updated visual studio 2019 to 16.5.0

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to be a problem in the Xamarin debugger client in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5. The issue is being tracked by the team in a Visual Studio Developer Community item: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/847661/error-preventing-debugging-xamarin-forms-after-dep.html

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by the exclusion of using an inherited classes without overridden methods.

for example base class defined in net standard  lib:

```
public class DFStorage
{
    public virtual bool SaveAppTextFile(...)
    {
        ...
    }
    public virtual string GetAppTextFile(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

inherited in platform specific lib:
(without any overrides)

```
public class DFStorageIOS : DFStorage
{

}
```

App use platform class.

Overriding of one method was enough:

```
public class DFStorageIOS : DFStorage
{
    public override bool SaveAppTextFile(...)
    {
        return base.SaveAppTextFile(...);
    }
}
```